# Overlaying 2 or more shapes in a bitmap file created in C?

Tags: c, bitmap, pixel

i was working on a program that will, depending on the input draw, shapes of different colors onto a bitmap file, it works fine if i just have to draw one shape, but if i for example take two or more shapes it just draws over the old picture and the old one gets lost but i need them to overlay to create more complex pictures. Is there a way when i am writing to a bitmap file to skip over parts i dont want to write over ? I also tryed making an array in which i would save all the pixel data, but that doesnt work if i take a bitmap of a size larger than 800x800, depending on the size of the type of the elements of the array. I am open for any suggestion and comment. Thank you in advance.

Comment: 800x800x3 is about 2 mega bytes, you probably hit the stack limit. Allocate data on heap instead. Why are you not using an image library or why not the paint functions specific to the operating system?

Comment: Thank you very much, i haven't thought about that, very stupid of me, now it's all working. I made a pixel structure array and allocated memory for it and it works perfectly. Now i just edit the pixels in this array that i want to edit and then write to the actual bimap file.

Answer (score 1):

You need to draw the second shape using a transparent background, how you would do that is entirely up to you as you don't provide any information about what technology you are using.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning all the details, i am doing this in C and using only standard C libraries. I figured that out but i dont know exactly what to do to get a transparent background. thank you.

Comment: You need another bitmap to act as a mask. In that bitmap set the value to all 1s where the second shape is to be drawn and 0 elsewhere. Finally combine the result of the first draw with the second by: res1[i] = (res1[i] & ~mask[i]) | (res2[i] & mask[i]). Here 'res1' is the result of the first draw, 'res2' the second, 'mask' the masking bitmap I described and 'i' is the pixel index, this selects the new value from res2 where the second draw is to occur and the existing value from res1 everywhere else.